# Example of a weak convergent sequence that is not strongly convergent in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Here $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ is the space of non-negative integer sequences $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n|^p < \infty$$

So I'm looking for an example of a sequence in this space that converges in the weak topology but doesn't converge in the topology generated by the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e_1=(1,0,...), e_2=(0,1,0,..),...$ gives such a  sequence. It converges weakly because $(y_n) \in \ell^{p}$ implies $y_n \to 0$.